# Storing multiple rows in a variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple table(MyEmail) in SQL with some emails that need to be sent, for example:

```
ID  Email
1   name@yahoo.com
2   something2@yahoo.com
3   name3@google.com
4   something4@yahoo.com
```

I made a stored procedure(GetAddress) to collect them so I can later store them into a variable:

```
 SELECT  Email
 FROM dbo.MyEmai
```

I need help with the C# part of the code:

```
SqlCommand cmdMyEmails = new SqlCommand("GetAddress", connection);
cmdMyEmails.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
var MyEmails = (string)cmdMyEmails.ExecuteScalar();
```

This code returns only one row and I need all rows from the table to be selected and stored into the MyEmails variable.

I tried something like this but still no luck:

```
var MyEmails = (cmdMyEmails.ExecuteReader()).ToString();
```

Can someone help me with this?
I need all rows to be selected and stored into the MyEmails variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of trying things at random, check any ADO.NET tutorial. A reader is a *reader* that will read results. It's not the results themselves

Comment: Avoid the function ExecuteScalar=> it Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Comment: Yes I Agree, I need solution that select all rows

Comment: @freej17 no, you need an ADO.NET tutorial and/or course. You can find many good tutorials on Microsoft's documentation site, https://learn.microsoft.com. You can get access for 3 months to Pluralsight's courses through the also free Visual Studio Dev Essentials program

Comment: Ok that I allready know :D

Comment: @freej17 simply googling `ADO.NET ExecuteReader()` will return [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) as the very first result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I totally agrre with u, first google then stack question

Comment: try using **Dapper** Framework for SQL and believe me you'll never switch to conventional SqlCommand format again. **Dapper** was developed by Stackoverflow only to help developers like us!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in this [msdn tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var MyEmails= new List<Email>(); //I suposse MyEmails is a List of Email as an example
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{ 
   MyEmails.Add(new Email(){email=reader[0].ToString()}); // as an example 
}
```

You probably want to use any of [these methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) :

- `reader[0].ToString();` //if you know column 0 is the one that contains the email.
- `reader["email"].ToString();` //when email is the column name of the query result

Comment: This looks like best solution. I have one more question.
Should I declare Email as a namespace before this code?
This code is located in a webmethod.

Comment: Post MyEmails code plz. First think for what purpose you want the MyEmails instance

Answer (score 1):

just use datatable fill data in it and ExecuteReader()

```
DataTableresult = new DataTable();

SqlCommand cmdMyEmails = new SqlCommand("GetAddress", connection);
cmdMyEmails.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
result.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
```

updated

u can fill dataset using SqlDataAdapter

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlCommand cmdMyEmails = new SqlCommand("GetAddress", connection);
cmdMyEmails.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter()
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
sda.Fill(ds);
```

or fetch data using reader

```
SqlCommand cmdMyEmails = new SqlCommand("GetAddress", connection);
cmdMyEmails.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{ 
   string Emailid =  reader["Email"].ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your SQL statement with this one, and you will already get all the addresses as a single value, separated by ';', so you won't need to change a single line of your C# code :

```
select string_agg(Email, ';') as Email
from dbo.MyEmail
```

If you are using an SQL older than SQL Server 2017 the string_agg function is not available, so you will need to use this trick (using the XML built-in functions) :

```
select (select @Email + ';' 
        from dbo.MyEmail
        for xml path('')) as Email
```

Comment: Procedure or function '"GetAddress"' expects parameter '@Email', which was not supplied.
I think I need to change code somehow after all :D Can you help ?
@Marc Guillot

Comment: @freej17 I have changed both queries so you'll get the result as Email, like your original query. Please, try again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I'm using older version so I tried second query. 
Because of @Email i need some kind of code change in C#. Is Email now an output paramether ?

Comment: Is an output column, as it was on the query that you showed on the original post. SELECT  Email FROM dbo.MyEmai

Comment: @freej17 the only difference that I expect you would need to code is to expand the size of the Email parameter on GetAddress to something big, like varchar(4000), so it could now contain many addresses concatenated on a single string.